# definition of monotone increasing sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've started reading [All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/) with the hope of gaining understanding of machine learning fundamentals.
The author gives the following definition in the first chapter:

> A sequence of sets $A_1, A_2,\dots$ is **monotone increasing** if $A_1
>  \subset A_2 \subset \dots$ and we define $\lim_{n\rightarrow
>  \infty}A_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$.
>
> *(The author then analogously defines the
>   monotone decreasing sequence of sets.)*
>
> In either case, we will write $A_n \rightarrow A$.

It's obvious that for any finite *k*, $A_k = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_k$, so I guess it's an infinite extension of this. My problem is I don't really understand the motivation behind this definition; i.e. what it "buys us".

I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 3):

Among other things, such constructions help you define and understand the continuity of measures (which is basically a function defined on sets in a sigma algebra). For example, with the $A_n$s you have defined, and with a measure $\mu$,

$$ \lim \mu (A_n)=\mu (\lim A_n)$$

Compare this with standard continuity below to see the similarities:

$$ \lim f (x_n)=f (\lim x_n)$$

Comment: I had an inkling that it had to do continuity, but I don't really know much about sigma algebras; the author hasn't formalised them. I guess I'll put it on the back-burner for now.